# android make call from app hide number

Tags: android, android-intent

I in my app, I want to call a person on button click.

```
iv_call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:593987424"));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });
```

when user clicks the button android OS starts the call. Can I hide the phone number , so user shouldn't be able to see the number ?

[image]

Comment: No it's not possible we can't get any control to modify dialer info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. It's another app and it decides show number or not.